# Solving for a coordinate along an axis given a triangle (3 coordinates)

Tags: geometry, triangles

Not sure what the best, or most descriptive title is but here is my problem:

I have added a picture to help clarify it. I am trying to solve for the diamond position, more specificly I really only need the x (assuming x is red) distance to the line P1->P2. In the picture P2 is just Y translated relative to 0/0 but it may not always be the case.

How can I solve for this distance/position with respect to P1/P2 (they are not always fixed) but relative to 0/0.

[image]

Comment: Hint: draw two lines perpendicular to the $x$-axis and passing through $P1$ and $P2$ respectively, and use similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Since $\triangle OXP_2\sim\triangle AP_1P_2$,

\begin{align}
\frac{|XO|}{|P_2O|}
&=
\frac{|P_1A|}{|P_2A|}
,\\
X_x&=
\frac{|P_{2y}|\cdot|P_{1x}|}{|P_{1y}-P_{2y}|}
.
\end{align}